# git commit - unstage ; what to do?

Tags: git, commit, patch, openwrt

I did that patch in open wrt, I applied patch with *patch -p 1 -i filename.patch* + *git add filename.patch*   but when I check the status, I got that, Do I need to do something else?
thanks

```
/openwrt$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   target/linux/mvebu/patches-5.4/800-Add_Armada_38x_support_for_clk-cpu.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

New content listed in the index can be committed or reset. `to be committed` is meant as a reminder that you've `add`ed snapshots to the repo but haven't baked them in to a commit yet, the next line is reminding you you can back them out before writing a commit too. `add` and `reset` (and `checkout`) also have `-p`/`--patch` options, you can do things piecemeal, Git's got that "whatever's useful in your work" thing down so hard people can get a little lost.

Comment: thank you very much, so to be sure, after I did that ie; `applied patch + git add` and when I did `git status` I see my patchin green in terminal, so the file is in the kernel (openwrt) and if I ''make my image'' it will be there?   cause I see you comment : `to the repo but haven't baked them in to a commit yet`    . I dont know how to commit, I thought it was when I do ''git add''....... thanks

Comment: You'll need to spend more time with the git docs. Say `git help` and follow the bouncing ball, `git help -g` in particular lists great ways to get oriented when you're trying to wrap your head around\ the subjects of each of those guides.